# SQL Server: problem with string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm trying this as part of a big query:

```
(CONVERT(varchar(20), AZ_DTA_APP_AGE, 103) + ' ' + (CONVERT(varchar(20), AZ_DTA_APP_AGE, 108)) AS AZ_DTA_APP_AGE
```

Why it doesn't work?

I get:

> Syntax error near keyword 'AS'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1st convert is missing a ')'

```
(CONVERT(varchar(20), AZ_DTA_APP_AGE, 103)) + ' ' + (CONVERT(varchar(20), AZ_DTA_APP_AGE, 108)) AS AZ_DTA_APP_AGE`
```

Comment: Thank you, I lost my focus over something really stupid.. :-(